# What is the point of fetchAll?

Tags: php, pdo

To get the result from the database, you can do this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $r) { 
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($r);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

but it seem to work without using `fetchAll`, example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$result = $sth->execute();
foreach($result as $r) { 
  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($r);
  echo "</pre>";
 }
```

so what is the difference?

Comment: Thats weird because execute return TRUE or FALSE. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchAll` will read in all rows from the database resultset and make an array out of them, keeping it all in memory. Iterating over the resultset will fetch one row at a time from the server which will save resources on the PHP side (but may use more resources on the database server, depending on the database implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I assume that you are using php PDO

With fetchAll you can specify Fetch mode as an argument and fetchall provides more flexibility over the returned rows and fetchall will read all rows from database and translate into an array.

fetchall is lot more efficient in resource management compared to simple executes i guess. also the resource returned by execute is bool